# If .env file is not included in git then how the prod deployment works in ec2 , how the prod code gets access to variables?

Tags: django, express, deployment, environment-variables, devops

.env is included in gitignore ,then how do the prod code know the values.

I think that the jenkins handle this in order to maintain security , but please someone let me know how this works .Since i dont have much knowledge on devops side.

Answer (score 1):

great question.
in our company, we add another file `.env.template` will contain placeholders and also it will be very similar to the `.env` file so anyone who wants to deploy or set up his own `.env` could what keys he wants.